# What objects are covered by Enterprise Territory Management?

Tags: custom-object, sharing, territory-management, territory

I am trying to understand which objects can be shared using Enterprise Territory Management. Finding this has been difficult because most information that comes up in searches is related to the old Territory Management.

I did find this, from the old Territory Management:

> Territory management only affects accounts and the standard objects that have a master-detail relationship to accounts. For example, opportunities are included in territory management but leads are not.

Is that also true for Enterprise Territory Management, or is it possible to affect custom objects as well?

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise Territory Management is just the successor of the former Territory Management, with a couple of new features. You find details in the [Enterprise Territory Management Implementation Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_implementing_territory_mgmt2_guide.pdf).

Unfortunately, you still can't share a custom object to territories, just Accounts and objects that are related to Accounts, like Opportunities.

For a programmatic way of sharing custom objects to Territories you find details in [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/03/salesforce-territory-management-and-programmatic-sharing.html) on developer.salesforce.com.